# Get login name in to another windows form in C#

Tags: c#, session, authentication

I am creating a windows application and I have created a login page that is Authenticated with database so I want to show my login name as a label in home page after login. How can I make it. If I want to create a session how to create it ?

Comment: Post some code as well so that you can know where you need to work.

Comment: blank out without any idea. i have created login page and a main page login valued are validated and Authenticating form my login database.

Comment: ok, then try some of the hints given below.

Comment: You do not specify if this is webforms or winforms.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as that for web application and not for window application. :)

Comment: cheers still searching bt thanks for ur try :D

Answer (score 2):

You can set your login name as below code on Form1 login button click event:

```
var frm2 = new Form2("set login name");
frm2.Show();
```

and on `Form2` constructor you can use the below code:

```
public Form2(string s)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1.Text = s;
}
```

Comment: ("set login name") i am confused here

Comment: @user2979006 instead of "set login name", you can pass the data you want to show like the current logged in user's name eg- "Vamsi"

Comment: no it wont work. I will send variable names depend on database and user names. it is authenticated one with  SQL i am having ore than 10 user name in my table

Comment: Can u plz add some code which  u use for authentication on login button click event?

Comment: '
                if (DBConnection.Authenticate(textBox_usrID.Text.Trim(), textBox_pwd.Text.Trim(), comboBox_Role.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    main_menu menu = new main_menu();
                    menu.Show();
                    this.Hide();

                                      
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
                }
            }
        }'

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that:

**Main form:**

```
public class MainForm
{
   public string LoginName { get; set; }

   public void ShowChildForm()
   {
      var childForm = new ChildForm(this);
      childForm.Show();
   }
}
```

**Child form:**

```
public class ChildForm
{
   public MainForm Parent { get; set; }

   public string LoginName 
   {
      get
      {
         return Parent.LoginName;
      }
   } 

   public ChildForm(MainForm mainForm)
   {
      Parent = mainForm;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While redirecting to second form (form2) from login form(form1) do the following-

**form 1**

```
 Form2 f2 = new Form2("yourLoginName");
 f2.Show();
```

**Form 2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    string sname;

    public Form2(string name, string id, Form a)
    {
        sname = name;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = sname; // Set your login name on label
    }
}
```

Comment: ("yourLoginName") i am confused here. i will give multiple names depends on user name so how to do it

Comment: U cam use Form2 f2 = new Form2(txtloginName.txt);

Answer (score 0):

Form 1:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();

        MessageBox.Show(f2.transfer(true).ToString()); //Returns the Text When f2 closed 
    }
```

Form 2:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    string textToTransfer = "";

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textToTransfer = textBox1.Text;
        transfer(true);
        this.Close();
    }

    public string transfer(Boolean wantToTransfer) //You could also do this without the Boolean
    {
        if (wantToTransfer == true)
        {
            textToTransfer = "Succes";
        }
        else
        {
            textToTransfer = "nope";
        }

        return textToTransfer;
    }
```

Looks much but it isnt...have fun with it :)